# php CURLOPT_RESOLVE doesn't work

Tags: php, curl

I'm on Centos 6, PHP 5.6.35,

> curl 7.59.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.59.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e
> zlib/1.2.3 c-ares/1.14.0 libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.6.0

I'm trying to force curl to use an IP (webserver in my LAN) with HTTPS :

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://" . $domain . "/");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, array( $domain . ":443:192.168.1.10"));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

It keeps connecting to the real public IP of $domain.
I also get this :

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RESOLVE - assumed 'CURLOPT_RESOLVE' in ...
>
> PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in ...

Comment: Surprising. In the PHP 5.6.35 source, we can see the constant declaration for cURL >= 7.21.3 : https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/47699a24e6fe9b9f2654d4f2537cfdb7c089b27f/ext/curl/interface.c#L1173

Comment: Could you try with this value `10203` (`0x27DB`)? `curl_setopt($ch, 10203, array( $domain . ":443:192.168.1.10"));`

Comment: With 10203, no more Notice or Warning, but it's still using the real IP.

Comment: Does `print_r(curl_version());` outputs the same version (7.59.0)?

Comment: [version] => 7.59.0, [version_number] => 473856, [age] => 4, [features] => 3113885

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the curl 7.59 version from city-fan doesn't work.

I've tested on a Centos 7 with

> curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.21 Basic
>   ECC zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3

and it works.